# What is the class of an Embedded asset?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

What is the class of an embedded asset?

```
[Embed(source="picture.png")]
public static const picture:Class;
```

what is the class of:

```
new picture();
```

what superclasses does it inherit?  i thought it would be Sprite, but it gave me a TypeError.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [`BitmapAsset`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/BitmapAsset.html).